# Entering text into the omnibar programmatically

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts, address-bar

Is it possible to enter text from an extension or userscript into the address bar/omnibox in google chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is not possible.  From [the extension developer FAQ](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq.html#faq-dev-05):

> **Can extensions create UI outside of the rendered web page?**
>
> Yes, your **extension may add buttons** to the Chrome browser's user interface. See browser actions and page actions for more information.
>
> An **extension may also create popup notifications**, which exist outside of the browser window. See the desktop notifications documentation for more details.

No mention is made of overwriting the ***omnibox***, and [the extension API documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/docs.html) provides no function that looks able to do that.
This is probably for the best, as having an arbitrary write capability, to the *omnibox*, would invite way too much mischief.

---

You can, however use [the `chrome.omnibox` API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox.html) to create a custom list of choices that your extension can react to.  The user must initiate this by typing your extension's keyword.  See [the *Omnibox Example* extension code](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html#omnibox).